# Error: Invalid number of parameters for "Method". Got 3 expected 2!

Tags: web3js, react

I have React app that executes a Smart Contract payable function at some point. The call is below:

```
try {
  await contract.methods
    .post(
      this.state.param1,
      `${this.state.param2}`,
      {
        from: account,
        value: Number(web3.utils.toWei(`${value}`)),
        gas: 400000,
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei("3", "gwei")
      }
    )
    .call();
} catch (error) {
  // Catch any errors for any of the above operations.
  alert(
    `Failed to load web3, accounts, or contract. Check console for details.`
  );
  console.error(error);
}
```

When executed, it returns an error `Error: Invalid number of parameters for "post". Got 3 expected 2!`

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. Tried recompiling and migrating the contract, nothing works so far. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the parameters incorrectly. See [contract.myMethod.call](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call). If you are trying to call a `view function`, use:

```
contract.methods
    .post(
      this.state.param1,
      `${this.state.param2}`
    )
    .call( {
        from: account,
        value: web3.utils.toWei(`${value}`),
        gas: 400000,
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei("3", "gwei")
      });
```

Replace call with `send` if you are trying to update some state.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, now I'm getting: `Error: Please pass numbers as strings or BN objects to avoid precision errors.`

Comment: You don't need Number around value since numbers suck when the value gets big. Always use BN when dealing with large numbers. You can use `web3.utils.toBN()` to convert Number to BN.